# jQuery: Check and listen if radio button is checked

Tags: jquery

I have the following code to check if radio button is checked:

```
if(jQuery("input:radio[name=type]").is(":checked")){
   // do stuff
}
```

It works on page load. But I want to listen for any changes. So once the page is loaded, if user clicks on it, then do stuff. How do I improve my code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> want to listen for any changes. So once the page is loaded, if user
>   clicks on it, then do stuff.

Try utilizing [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on) , `change` event

```
jQuery("input:radio[name=type]").on("change", function() {
  if (jQuery(this).is(":checked")) {
   // do stuff
  }
})
// trigger `change` event at page load
.change();
```

---

```js
jQuery(function() {
  jQuery("input:radio[name=type]").on("change", function() {
      if (jQuery(this).is(":checked")) {
        // do stuff
        alert(this.checked)
      }
    })
    // trigger `change` event at page load
    .change();
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<input type="radio" name="type" checked="true" />
```

---

Alternatively , define `handler` as a named function , call named function at both page load , and at change event

```js
jQuery(function() {
  
  function changeHandler() {
      if (jQuery(this).is(":checked")) {
        // do stuff
        alert(this.checked)
      }
    }
  
  // call `changeHandler` with `this`
  // set to `jQuery("input:radio[name=type]")[0]` element
  changeHandler.call(jQuery("input:radio[name=type]")[0]);
  
  jQuery("input:radio[name=type]").on("change", changeHandler);

})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<input type="radio" name="type" checked="true" />
```

Comment: Ah wait. It looks like it works if you click on it, but on page load if the radio button is already checked, then it doesn't work (my original code did). Do you have a fix for this so it checks if it is already checked on pageload? Thanks.

Comment: @HenrikPetterson Try chaining `.change()` to close of `.on()` to trigger `change` event at page load, see updated post.

Comment: Can you kindly demonstrate how by editing your answer?

Comment: I wouldn't advice triggering .change() on page load. This will trigger **all** change events and not just this one. I'm sure there is a better approach to this.

Comment: @HenrikPetterson See updated post, added stacksnippets to demonstrate.

Comment: @GaryWoods An alternative approach could be to define `handler` as a named function , call named function at both page load , and at `change` event

Comment: @guest271314 That's it. I was going to post a similar answer but I will leave it to you since you're there already. I'd suggest editing your answer with this approach for completeness. 1+ regardless.